# Dynamically define react when processing tsx files in node

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

I'm writing a migration script which pulls in a load of tsx files from a next.js project. The code so far looks like this:

```js
import fs from "node:fs";
import { readdir } from "node:fs/promises";
import path from "node:path";
import { inspect } from "node:util";

import React from "react";
import jsx2json from "jsx2json";
import { NdJson } from "json-nd";
import * as url from "url";

import test from "./data/james/cementing-tests/CSS/CSS-Selectors.tsx";

const inspectOptions = {
  depth: null,
  colors: true,
};

const targetDir = "./data/james/cementing-tests/";

(async function () {

  try {

    const directoryEntries = await readdir(targetDir, {
      withFileTypes: true,
      recursive: true,
    });
    console.log(inspect(directoryEntries, inspectOptions))

    const relevantFiles = directoryEntries.filter((f) => f.name !== 'index.tsx' && f.name.endsWith('.tsx'))

    for (const {path:filePath, name:fileName } of relevantFiles) {
      const fullPath = path.join(filePath, fileName);
      console.log('fullPath', fullPath);
      const data = await import(`./${fullPath}`); // ERROR HAPPENS HERE
    }

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }

})();
```

and is run with like so:

```bash
 node --import=tsx ./ct-mig.mjs;
```

Being next.js files they don't have the react import at the top of each file, so when processing separately I get `ReferenceError: React is not defined`.

Can anyone suggest a way to automatically put react into scope?

Comment: What is your migration code meant to do? What are you going to with `data`? `tsx` files are just text files so are you sure you're meant to `import` them rather than just read them?

Comment: @Andy Eventually I'll process the tsx that's in them into ndjson before uploading them to a CMS.

IF I put the react import in manually tit works but I don't want to have to do that for all the files, so I was wondering if there was a fast way

Comment: try to make React available globally
global.React = React;

Comment: Isn’t `data` just going to be the module’s exports?

Comment: @James Yes it is. You can use the default getter from there

Comment: @AdrianBiba Obvious when you think about it! TY! If you put it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm glad I helped you out @user1775718